# Horizontal Scroll using flexbox not working with mousewheel

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, flexbox

This is happening for WooCommerce product galleries. I've eliminated all other CSS from the site's theme and plugin, but I'm still not able to scroll suing my mousewheel. Using my mouse to click and drag the scrollbar works, but I want it to work with the mousewheel as well.

Below is the CSS, you can see the issue here:
https://wysostage.wpengine.com/product/short-sleeve-unisex-t-shirt/

[image: SCREENSHOT OF HORIZONTAL SCROLL AREA]

HTML:

```
    <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
<li><img src="/wp-content/uploads/unisex-staple-t-shirt-heather-deep-teal-front-61941bc1b72b5-100x100.jpg" class="flex-active" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="/wp-content/uploads/unisex-staple-t-shirt-black-heather-front-61941bc1b8452-100x100.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="/wp-content/uploads/unisex-staple-t-shirt-red-front-61941bc1b8828-100x100.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="/wp-content/uploads/unisex-staple-t-shirt-forest-front-61941bc1b8e64-100x100.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="/wp-content/uploads/unisex-staple-t-shirt-true-royal-front-61941bc1b98ad-100x100.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="/wp-content/uploads/unisex-staple-t-shirt-berry-front-61941bc1bac7a-100x100.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="/wp-content/uploads/unisex-staple-t-shirt-kelly-front-61941bc1bc715-100x100.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="/wp-content/uploads/unisex-staple-t-shirt-heather-prism-lilac-front-61941bc1be235-100x100.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
<li><img src="/wp-content/uploads/unisex-staple-t-shirt-heather-prism-mint-front-61941bc1c00aa-100x100.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
 .woocommerce div.product div.images .flex-control-thumbs {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}

.woocommerce div.product div.images .flex-control-thumbs li {
    padding: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 25%;
    flex: 1 0 25%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    clear: none !important;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/

Comment: @MahmouDSkafi I've tried this but it does not work since the width/height of the parent/child elements are responsive.